# Optimal heading visual weight to paragraph visual weight ratio

Tags: navigation, text, hierarchy, font-weight

Is there any research about optimal heading visual weight to paragraph visual weight ratio?

I have noticed myself that extra large and bold headings make me feel comfortable to skim a long text but this is just a subjective feeling.

*Similar questions:*

- [Ideal visual weight of indicators such as dropdown triangle](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82028/ideal-visual-weight-of-indicators-such-as-dropdown-triangle)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different considerations that have already been covered under the general principle of Readibility and Legibility, and without some idea about the exact context/use case that you are designing for (and it seems like there is more than one), I think there are some guiding principles you can use to work out the best balance between the heading and paragraph visual weight:

- **Ratio of headings to paragraph counts**: the visual weight of the headings will be more effective if there is a much smaller number of headings compared to blocks of paragraph text
- **length of heading / average word count in paragraph**: again the visual weight of the headings will be impacted if the number of words in the heading is very long (e.g. more than one line) and if the word count of the paragraphs are low (e.g. less than two lines)
- **number of hierarchies in visual weight**: if there are many level of visual weight applied to the text it will also lose the effect of the visual weight, so depending on the length and complexity of the text you will need to try and create as few levels as possible to make the highlight stand out more
- **other interactions**: if you can expand or collapse different sections of the heading or paragraph, or if there are microinteractions or visual effects for zooming in or out these will also impact on the perceived visual weight

Comment: There's no particular use case, I am asking in general. I am looking to achieve not only readability and legibility, but also aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

This is typographical question and typography as a topic has been around for a very long time.

So I am confident there will be some research about optimal visual weight for headings out there, however I am curious why you need *academic* research, when the core principles are well known?

Basically you just need to understand the concepts of **Readability** & **Legibility**.

Academic research can be found but access to some of it may be difficult. A quick Google search might identify some of them.

There are also plenty of web resources which discuss the core principles, many of which are based on the Gestalt Principles of Perception:

http://vanseodesign.com/web-design/gestalt-principles-of-perception/

As you are primarily interested in visual weight, this link discusses these principles:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/12/design-principles-visual-weight-direction/

Comment: Thanks, well, my question does cover readibility but it is more directed towards ensuring easy and precise skimming. In some cases we have long texts requiring prolonged reading (articles, books, etc), but in other cases all needed is skimming until you find the needed piece of information (e.g. FAQ page).

Comment: The better the Readable & Legibility, and applying the Gestalt principles, will make it easier to skim.